# Passing references of different objects into a class with one object in the constructor

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I'm having some issues with a game that I am trying to code at university. I have a collision manager class that holds functions for various collisions with the player and the enemies. In this class I have pointer objects of the player and each enemy, so that I can access various collision response member functions of the objects involved. This all worked fine when I was testing the collisions with the player and one of each enemy, but now that I am trying to build a level with multiple enemies, I am having problems accessing the multiple enemies from the collision detector.

I've tried to trim the fat and not leave too much unimportant code, but an example of what I'm trying to do:

In the header:

```
class CollisionManager
{
public:

    CollisionManager(Player& play, Enemy* en);
    ~CollisionManager();

    void update();

private:
    Player* player;
    Enemy* enemy;
};
```

In the cpp file

```
CollisionManager::CollisionManager(Player& play, Enemy* en) :
    player(&play),
    enemy(en)
{

}
void CollisionManager::update()
{
    // What happens when the enemy and the player collide under various circumstances
}
```

Like I said, this works fine if it's just one player and one enemy, but if I want multiple enemies, how can I get them to all access these collision detections?

I've tried creating an array or vector of enemies along with an enemy pointer (in the level class) that cycles through the various enemies.

I've tried changing the constructor parameter in the CollisionManager class to take a vector as an argument and then pass the vector of enemies to it from the level class.

This is what I currently have in my level file:
In the header

```
class Level : BaseLevel {
private:
    CollisionManager collisions;
    Player player;
    Enemy* enemy;
    //std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
    //Enemy enemies[6];

}
```

The two enemies (array and vector) are to show two examples that I've tried.

In the cpp file:

```
Level::Level() :
    collisions(player, enemy)
{
    enemy = NULL; // I'm not sure if this is necessary? To stop it being initialized as a null pointer
    // Use this if enemies is a vector and not an array
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        enemies.push_back(Enemy());
    }
}
void Level::update(float dt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        enemy = &enemies[i];
        collisions.update();
    }
}
```

I debugged this an it is telling me that enemy is a NULLPTR. I am currently researching how to work around this but can't seem to find a solution.

I feel like I must be missing some basic fundamental thing here but I can't for the life of me see how I can work around this without taking all of my functionality from the CollisionManager class and dumping it in the level so that it can be accessed by everything, but I would prefer not to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm very happy to provide further information/code.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Don't type in code manually into the question (which it likely to produce artifacts like `Class` with a capital `C` etc). Create the MRE offline and copy/paste it into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I believe I have done this.

Comment: Better, but in the `CollisionManager`'s constructor's initializer list you have `enemy(en)` - but there is no `enemy` member variable in `CollisionManager` (the member `en` should probably be renamed `enemy`).

Comment: D'oh! But that wasn't what was tripping me up -- I had a few different enemy types so I thought I would just condense them to enemy for the sake of this post rather than having demons, knights, zombies etc which seemed like unnecessary detail.

Comment: That intention is good - but please put a minimal example that actually compiles (if compiling isn't the problem) in the question. Paste the portions needed into an online compiler (like https://godbolt.com/) if needed. We don't need to see the code as individual files (if that's not part of the problem). One minimal chunk of code will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I was approaching this the completely wrong way around -- instead of using pointers to the objects to access their member functions in the CollisionManager, I just included references for the player and enemy as parameters to the functions that hold the collision response, and then used the player and enemy objects in the level as arguments when calling these functions. Sorry if that seems very obvious (it does to me now!), I'm still very new to all this!